# R Shift Multiple Rows On A Condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the data below.  I want to shift the rows with R so that none of the jobs will start on a weekend day.  I know how to so a simple shift of all rows, but I'm not sure how to do this in R because it would require some kind of recursion to continue shifting the rows as the first shift could cause a job to start on a weekend, where it previously had not.  Any suggestions?

```
Day of Week   Date          Job     Job Start
Sunday        12/1/19       Job1    12/1/19
Monday        12/2/19       Job1    12/1/19
Tuesday       12/3/19       Job2    12/3/19
Wednesday     12/4/19       Job2    12/3/19
Thursday      12/5/19       Job2    12/3/19
Friday        12/6/19       Job3    12/6/19
Saturday      12/7/19       Job3    12/6/19
Sunday        12/8/19       NA      NA
Monday        12/9/19       NA      NA
Tuesday       12/10/19      NA      NA
```

Here is the table result I am looking for.

```
Day of Week     Date        Job      Job Start
Sunday          12/1/19     NA       NA
Monday          12/2/19     Job1    12/2/19
Tuesday         12/3/19     Job1    12/2/19
Wednesday       12/4/19     Job2    12/4/19
Thursday        12/5/19     Job2    12/4/19
Friday          12/6/19     Job2    12/4/19
Saturday        12/7/19     NA      NA
Sunday          12/8/19     NA      NA
Monday          12/9/19     Job3    12/9/19
Tuesday         12/10/19    Job3    12/9/19
```

Comment: Job3 starts on Friday, which is not a weekend day. Why is it moved?

Comment: Job3 starts on a weekday in the original example, but pushing forward Job1 would then push Job3 to start on a Saturday.  Job3 would then need to be pushed to Monday.

Comment: The job start is the first day the job started so the third row changed to 12/2/2019 because Job1 moved forward to now start on 12/2/2019 instead of 12/1/2019

Answer (score 0):

Please add a reproducible minimal example. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Without that it's difficult for us to help you. But I'll try anyways ;)

```
data$Job_Start <- as.Date(data$Job_Start, "%d/%m/%y")
data$New_Job_Start <- ifelse(data$Day_of_Week %in% "Saturday", data$Job_Start + 2, data$Job_Start)
data$Day_of_Week <- ifelse(data$Day_of_Week %in% "Saturday", "Monday", data$Day_of_Week)
data$New_Job_Start <- ifelse(data$Day_of_Week %in% "Sunday", data$Job_Start + 1, data$Job_Start)
data$Day_of_Week <- ifelse(data$Day_of_Week %in% "Sunday", "Monday", data$Day_of_Week)
```